# Deleting files on my macbook is not affecting the storage space?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

How do I solve this problem? The storage space does not increase when I delete files. Yesterday, I deleted 250MB of files but made zero change to storage space. I have emptied the trash. I don't use Time Machine

Comment: It wont do it instantly, till the Spotlight has finished re indexing. Or try to restart.

Comment: restarting doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

[GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/) is a great app to visualize the files taking up the most space on your Mac. Next time you want to delete a file, use GP to scan your computer before and after you empty the Trash, and see what's still taking up space.

Comment: Or better OmniDiskSweeper - see other questions for a fuller list

Comment: I don't need an app to identity large files. No matter what file I delete, it is not increasing my storage space

Comment: But if you run a scan, delete space-hogging items, and then run a second scan, you can see where that excess space went.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting the computer. It may have not refreshed the current available storage.

Comment: restarting doesn't work